# Estimation the computation complexity of algorithm with more that one choice

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms, backpropagation

#### The problem:

We have a weighted graph $G=(V, E, W)$ with $|V| = n$, $|E| = n-1$ and $W$ is set of edge's weight. The graph $G$ includes one ring on $n_1 \geq 3$ nodes and $n_2$ isolated nodes, $n_1+ n_2 = n$.

We want to connect isolated nodes to the ring using an edge weight (euclidean distance between nodes and edges) as the feature for connection. The  ring's weight must be minimal.

#### Algorithm

1. select an edge $(u,v) \in E$
2. match to the edge $(u,v)$ the minimum distance to isolated nodes (this is an edge's weight)
3. repeat steps 1-2 for all edges
4. find the edge $(u,v)_{\min}$ with the global minimum weight $\arg \min_{(u,v) \in E} W$
5. connect the head $u$ and tail $v$ of specifited edge $(u,v)_{\min}$ with the corresponded isolated node $a$ by adding two edges $(u,a)$ and $(a,v)$
6. delete the edge $(u,v)_{\min}$ from the triangle $\{(u,a), (a,v), (v,u)\} \subset E$
7. repeat steps the 1-5 while the set of isolated nodes is not empty.

In the wortest case on step 4 we can have more one edges (some edges can have the same weight) and we can randomly select one of them. But we need to store weight of non-used edges for the possible back propogation on the next steps.

**Problem.** How to estimate the computation complexity of the proposed algorithm?

My attemp is:

1. $n$ elementary operations
2. $n_2$ elementary operations
3. $n \cdot (n-1)$ elementary operations
4. $n^2/2 - n$ elementary operations, if $W$ is simmetric matrix with zero diagonal and all elements are different on all steps (one choice)
5. $2$ elementary operations
6. $1$ elementary operation
7. $n$ elementary operations

The complexity is $O(n^2)$.